# Ошибка при запуске php END_OF_LINE

Tags: php, apache

При запуске php выскакивает ошибка

```
syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE, expecting '=' in C:\WebServers\local\PHP\php.ini on line 340
```

Вот это 340 строка:

```
;Нужно или нет определять различные переменные Syslog, такие как
```

архив с файлом: http://www.ex.ua/321647604110

Comment: Ошибка выше где-то; приведите несколько непустых строк выше. Присвоение неверно сделано.

Comment: @Regent, да строк пять-десять перед трёхсотсороковой будет, думаю, вполне достаточно.

Comment: там идут записи-комментарии.

Comment: @Lol, в комментариях нет форматирования. вставьте, пожалуйста, строки (включая и 340-ю) в тело вопроса. оформление кода: четыре пробела в начале строки, начало и конец кода отделяются пустыми строками.

Comment: @Lol, вставьте, пожалуйста, эти строки в **сам вопрос** (отредактировав его с помощью кнопки «править»). в комментарии не видно, где конец и начало строки.

Comment: @alexander barakin вот так

Comment: @Lol, не вижу в приведённых строках ошибок синтаксиса. возможно, ошибка где-то раньше. выложите куда-нибудь **весь** этот файл, пожалуйста.

Comment: Может чего посвежее поставить, заодно и конфиг новый будет? (глядя на register_globals и magic_quotes)

Comment: @Lol, кстати, в файле могут быть смешаны символы первода строк, поэтому лучше будет его запаковать каким-нибудь архиватором и выложить архив.

Comment: @alexander barakin https://yadi.sk/i/z7lapJ92hQbzD попробуйте тут скачать

Comment: Вставляйте текстовые данные на pastebin.com и подобных.

Comment: @alexander barakin http://pastebin.com/APP0jKaF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**основная ошибка:**

в начале файла присутствуют три символа с 16-ричным кодами `ef bb bf`.

**вторая найденная ошибка:**

синтаксическая — в 411 строке. вот строки с 409 по 411:

```
mysql.default_socket=
 ; Хост по умолчанию для mysql_connect() (не работает в безопасном
 режиме).
```

как видим, 411-я строка не закомментирована. надо поставить `;` в её начало.

**третья (предположительная) ошибка:**

файл имеет *dos*-овские окончания строк и, возможно, смесь из разных окончаний строк, с чем, теоретически, могут быть проблемы.

я удалил эти три первых символа и выложил [архив](https://yadi.sk/d/TG3fYqeThQg2J) с двумя версиями файла: с *dos*-овскими окончаниями строк и с *unix*-овскими. второй — на тот случай, если если `php` не поймёт «неродные» для него *dos*-овские окончания строк.

---

исправить первую и третью ошибки можно двумя командами вида (в операционной системе *gnu/linux*):

```
$ dos2unix файл
$ unix2dos файл
```

из файла будут удалены «нечитабельные» символы (вставляемые в начало файла некоторыми редакторами), а окончания строк (в случае их смешивания внутри одного файла некоторыми редакторами) будут «приведены к одному знаменателю».

Comment: точно, но ошибка все равно там же выскакивает...

Comment: выложите, пожалуйста, как я и просил, файл **целиком**. проще всего это сделать, заархивировав его любым архиватором, и выложив архив.

Comment: через какой сайт вам удобнее всего скинуть?

Comment: через тот, где не надо регистрироваться и/или устанавливать flash-player.

Comment: http://www.ex.ua/321647604110

Comment: @Lol, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ошибки больше не выбивает.

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой

> E:\tools\php-7.1>php -m
>
> PHP:  syntax error, unexpected END_OF_LINE, expecting '=' in
>   E:\tools\php-7.1\php.ini on line 2

Посмотрел конфг и сравнил два дефолтных:

```
php.ini-development
php.ini-production
```

В начале строк в `php.ini` после переименования! оказались строки `fv[PHP]` вместо, просто `[PHP]`

Решилось удалением вначале этих самых неясных букв "fv"